# _storageReference.getMetadata() doesn't work

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

this is my code :

```
StorageReference RiverRef;
StorageReference _storageReference;
_storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();


 RiverRef = _storageReference.child(_FirebaseUser.getEmail() + "/contacts.txt");

    RiverRef.getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(StorageMetadata storageMetadata) {
            // Metadata now contains the metadata for 'images/forest.jpg'
            _date[0] = new Date(storageMetadata.getCreationTimeMillis());
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
            String dateFormatted = formatter.format(_date[0]);
            ifThereIsFile = true;
            //System.out.println(storageMetadata.getCreationTimeMillis());
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            ifThereIsFile = false;
        }
    });
```

for some reason this is not even get into the "onsuccess" 
there is a file call that name by the way.

any idea ?

Comment: can you define what **doesn't work** is?

Comment: when i chek if the 'ifThereIsFile' is true , he false.

Comment: someone ???????

Comment: @רפאלחדד Can you trace if on execution it really goes into addOnSuccessListener or in the addOnFailureListener. Because I don't see any initialization of the ifThereIsFile boolean and it may be false by default... Just a double check...

Comment: @רפאלחדד And also, do you have any log?

Comment: i start with the bollean = false but i execute the func before i chek the flag

Comment: no i dont have any log

Comment: @רפאלחדד In android studio you should get the stack trace... Without any stack trace it will be difficult to help you. The very first step in order to debug this is to have a way to see if you go into the onSuccess() or in the onFailure() methods. Relying only on the value of ifThereIsFile is not 100% sufficient, as mentioned above.